# Find neighborhoods such that $f$ is bijective

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inverse

I got a function $f$
$$
f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2, (x, y) \mapsto f(x,y) := e^x (\cos y, \sin y)
$$

which is obviously not bijective because it is periodic in the second argument
$$
f(x, y) = f(x, 2k \pi y)
$$

for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Now I need to find neighborhoods around $(x_0, y_0) = (0, \pi / 2)$ and $f(x_0, y_0)$ such that the restriction of $f$ is bijective. So to "invalidate" the equation above we could take $\mathbb{R} \times [0, 2\pi]$

But how would that look like as a neighborhood? Am I only allowed to take symmetric neighborhoods, i.e. balls around $(x_0, y_0)$?

Comment: Recall that a neighborhood of a point $P$ in $\mathbb R^2$ is just a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ that contains an open set containing $P.$ Perhaps you should focus on finding an open ball $B$ containing the point $(0, \pi / 2)$ such that $f$ is injective on $B;$ then, you can extend this to a neighborhood of $\mathbb R^2$ containing $B$ such that $f$ is also surjective. For this, you can use the fact that $e^x > 0.$ Like you said, $f$ fails to be injective due to the fact that $\cos y$ and $\sin y$ are not injective.